# ¿Cómo agregar OnClickListener en RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-studio, recyclerview, cardview

Tengo un `RecyclerView` que tiene `CardView`, quiero que al darle click en el `CardView` me mande a otra actividad.

Aqui esta mi clase `Adapter`

```
public class TareaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TareaAdapter.TareaViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<TareaObj> tareas;
    CardView card;
    private Activity activity;

    public TareaAdapter(ArrayList<TareaObj> tareas, Activity activity) {
        this.tareas = tareas;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public TareaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_card_tarea, viewGroup, false);
//        card.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        return new TareaViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TareaViewHolder tareaViewHolder, int i) {
        TareaObj tarea = tareas.get(i);
        tareaViewHolder.idUsuario.setText(tarea.getIdUsuario());
        tareaViewHolder.prospectoId.setText(tarea.getProspectoId());
        tareaViewHolder.nombre.setText(tarea.getNombre());
        tareaViewHolder.email.setText(tarea.getEmail());
        tareaViewHolder.telefono.setText(tarea.getTelefono());
        tareaViewHolder.tareaCodigo.setText(tarea.getCodigoTarea());
        tareaViewHolder.descripcion.setText(tarea.getTareaDescripcion());
        tareaViewHolder.tareaTipoClave.setText(tarea.getTareaTipoClave());
        tareaViewHolder.fechaProgra.setText(tarea.getTareaFechaProg());

      //  card.findViewById(R.id.cardView);

  /*      tareaViewHolder.card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Ejemplo.class);
                activity.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });*/

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() { //Cantidad de elementos que contiene la lista
        return tareas.size();
    }

    public static class TareaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView idUsuario, prospectoId, nombre, email, telefono,
                tareaCodigo, descripcion, tareaTipoClave, fechaProgra;
        private CardView card;

        public TareaViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            idUsuario = itemView.findViewById(R.id.etUsuarioT);
            prospectoId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.etProspectoIdT);
            nombre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.etProspectoNombreT);
            email = itemView.findViewById(R.id.etProspectoEmailT);
            telefono = itemView.findViewById(R.id.etProspectoTelT);
            tareaCodigo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.etProspectoCodigoT);
            tareaTipoClave = itemView.findViewById(R.id.etTareaTipoCve);
            fechaProgra = itemView.findViewById(R.id.etFechaProgramada);
            descripcion = itemView.findViewById(R.id.etTareDesc);
            }
        }
    }
```

Ya hice "clickeable" el `CardView` desde la vista (xml). 
Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Lo comentado es lo que he intentado pero no funciona me manda el siguiente mensaje de error:

> NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.CardView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu archivo `layout_card_tarea.xml` no se encuentra el `CardView`, debes tener este elemento definido dentro del layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        ...
        ...
```

De otra forma te marcará `NullPointerException`

---

Es correcto el código que habías realizado solo asegura agregar el `CardView` en el layout:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TareaViewHolder tareaViewHolder, int i) {
        TareaObj tarea = tareas.get(i);
        tareaViewHolder.idUsuario.setText(tarea.getIdUsuario());
        tareaViewHolder.prospectoId.setText(tarea.getProspectoId());
        tareaViewHolder.nombre.setText(tarea.getNombre());
        tareaViewHolder.email.setText(tarea.getEmail());
        tareaViewHolder.telefono.setText(tarea.getTelefono());
        tareaViewHolder.tareaCodigo.setText(tarea.getCodigoTarea());
        tareaViewHolder.descripcion.setText(tarea.getTareaDescripcion());
        tareaViewHolder.tareaTipoClave.setText(tarea.getTareaTipoClave());
        tareaViewHolder.fechaProgra.setText(tarea.getTareaFechaProg());

       card.findViewById(R.id.cardView);

         tareaViewHolder.card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Ejemplo.class);
                activity.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: muchas gracias tenias razon estaba llamando a otro elemento, ya lo chequé y ya me funciono! ¡Gracias!

Comment: Excelente Isabel, saludos!